# z-index for two asp:Chart controls won't work?

Tags: html, css, asp.net, charts

I want to place two Charts one over the other with z-index in a table cell so that I can make one chart visible at a time. When refreshing the chart, I want to update data with the chart beneath the visible chart then make the visible switch z-index to avoid flickering...But does not seem to work and don't know what I am doing wrong:

**Here is my CSS**

```
td.tdchart
{
width: 800px;
position: relative;
z-index: 100;
display: block;
}

.chartHidden
{
z-index: 200;
position: absolute;
top: 0; 
left: 0; 
width: 100%; 
height: 100%
}

.chartVisible
{
z-index: 300;
position: absolute;
top: 0; 
left: 0; 
width: 100%; 
height: 100%
}
```

**Here is the partial asp page**

```
<table>
<tr>
<td class="tdchart">
<div id="pChart1" runat="server" class="chartVisible">
<asp:Chart ID="Chart1" ...> </asp:Chart>
</div>

<div id="pChart1" runat="server" class="chartHidden">
<asp:Chart ID="Chart1" ...> </asp:Chart>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**asp code behind in Ajax timer**

```
pChart2.Attributes.Add("class", "chartVisible");
pChart1.Attributes.Add("class", "chartHidden");
```

Comment: avoid flickering? why can't you just update the first chart?

Comment: I am seeing that the chart flickers...if I use only one chart and update that in a timer call

Comment: Could you use an `<asp:UpdatePanel>`?

Comment: it is wrapped in a update panel as below:

Comment: Can you provide more of the html that includes the `<asp:UpdatePanel>` and the complete code behind function that interacts with the chart?

Comment: But this is how I have it in the aspx page:

    <tr>
    <td class="tdchart">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
 <div id="pChart1" runat="server">
        <asp:Chart ID="Chart1"> </asp:Chart>
        <asp:Chart ID="Chart2"> </asp:Chart>
 </div>
 <asp:Timer></asp:Timer>
    </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </td>
    </tr>

Comment: Can you update your original question with the updated code?

Comment: I am working on providing a link as I have a limit on how much I can post here

Comment: The following link has the zip file with VS2010 project

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6LALs6pb4ufUDBTLVRYbzN4QlU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I will take a look and post an answer if I find anything helpful

Comment: The following helps by creating another problem as showin the picture at the URL
`<style>
        .chartVisible {
            z-index: 300 !important;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>`
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6LALs6pb4ufanNFVjU0VFdNWGc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: As shown in the above picture the Charts are on top of the other but their alignment seems to get off from rest of the page...

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of a long shot since I haven't worked on a Web Forms project in awhile and I am unable to run the web app.

I really think that you do not need 2 identical charts. You should never have to have repeated code like that in order to avoid a flicker, it becomes a pain to manage and is not efficient. Keep your code DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself).

That being said, I think you should remove the second chart and focus on getting the first chart to update properly without flickering using the `<asp:UpdatePanel>`.

**Possible Fix**

I noticed your UpdatePanel is using the conditional setting:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
```

If you have this enabled you will need to trigger your Async postback manuelly. Either by calling `UpdatePanel2.Update()` in your code behind or setting up a trigger. I didn't see either of these (but I could have missed something).

I suggest you add this below your second timer:

```
        ...
        <asp:Timer ID="Timer2" runat="server" Interval = "10000" OnTick="Timer2_Tick" 
            Enabled="False"></asp:Timer>
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer2" EventName="Tick" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I believe this should trigger the UpdatePanel when the timer ticks and update your chart.

But please note this is an untested fix and I could be completely missing something

Comment: Thank you. But any child controls that are inside the UpdatePanel automatically do asyncpostback and the update panel refreshes its children without requiring manul Update call. You need to call the update if, say the timer is outside the UpdatePanel itself. 

I have this working in the code under UpdatePanel1. Adding the !important seemed to help except the page looks odd as shown below. Any idea?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6LALs6pb4ufanNFVjU0VFdNWGc/view?pli=1

Comment: lol I did miss something, but that makes sense. I see the screenshot but how are they not aligned properly? Because they are overlapping the white box above them?

Comment: You should also maybe try adding `pChart1.Attributes.Remove("class")` for each chart before you add the new class.